# Access overwritten fields of super class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

I have named one of my fields in my subclass the same as in my superclass. I have basically overwritten the fields in my parent class.

How can I distinguish the field from the base class from the field with the same name in the extended class?

Comment: Note: this is more usually called [*hiding*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html), rather than overwriting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword `super` is most of the times used in conjunction to accessing superclass methods, most of the times a constructor from the parent class .

The keyword `this`  is most of the times used to distinguish fields of the class from method parameters or local variables with the same name.

However, you can also use `super` to access fields of the superclass or `this` to call methods (which is redundant since all calls are virtual methods calls), or another constructor from the same class.

Here is an example of the usage for accessing fields.

```
public class Base {

    public int a = 1;
    protected int b = 2;
    private int c = 3;

    public Base(){

    }
}

public class Extended extends Base{

    public int a = 4;
    protected int b = 5;
    private int c = 6;

    public Extended(){

    }

    public void print(){
        //Fields from the superclass
        System.out.println(super.a);
        System.out.println(super.b);
        System.out.println(super.c); // not possible

        //Fields from the subclass
        System.out.println(this.a);
        System.out.println(this.b);
        System.out.println(this.c);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Extended ext = new Extended();
        ext.print();
    }
```

You can always rename the fields in your subclasses not to conflict, but if you want to distinguish a method parameter or local variable from the superclass field, use `super` as you would use `this`